# Cut and Paste Special font data, align the data pasted to other data in a different column in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, paste

Looking for a macro that can align data copied to data present in column A

I have my raw data as:
[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVSkk.png)

Then I have a macro that copies all the data in *Italics* from Column B to C

```
    Sub copy_Italic()
    'Narrations in Italics Copy
    Dim LastRow  As Long, x As Long, y As Long, txt1 As String, txt As String
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To LastRow
        txt1 = ""
        txt = Cells(x, 2)
        If txt <> "" Then
            For y = Len(txt) To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(x, 2).Characters(Start:=y, Length:=1).Font.Italic Then
                    txt1 = Cells(x, 2).Characters(Start:=y, Length:=1).Text & txt1
                End If
            Next y
            Cells(x, 3) = txt1
        End If
        End Sub
```

So I need a macro that picks the narration data in column C, then aligns them to data available in Column A and also picks the "entered by..." text and pastes it on Column D while aligning to Column A, then deletes the unwanted rows see result:
[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33kA3.png)

Thanks. Feel free to offer improvements to the macro above too!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use code below. if will loop through your data and add all `italic values` to column `C` in respective row. Then it will filter `"entered by"` word and add that value to column `D` (also in respective row). After that, it will delete all rows in column `B` that are written in italic.

```
Sub copy_Italic()
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & x) <> 0 Then
        Row = x
        txt = Cells(x, 2)
        If txt <> "" Then
            For y = Len(txt) To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(x, 2).Characters(Start:=y, Length:=1).Font.Italic Then
                    txt1 = Cells(x, 2).Characters(Start:=y, Length:=1).Text & txt1
                End If
            Next y
                If InStr(LCase(txt1), "entered by") = 1 Then
                Cells(Row, 4) = txt1
                Else
                Debug.Print txtl
                    For Z = 1 To 10
                    If Range("c" & Row + Z - 1).Value = "" Then

                          Cells(Row + Z - 1, 3) = txt1
                          GoTo Tu:
                    End If
                    Next Z
                End If
Tu:
    End If
Else
        txt1 = ""
        txt = Cells(x, 2)
        If txt <> "" Then
            For y = Len(txt) To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(x, 2).Characters(Start:=y, Length:=1).Font.Italic Then
                    txt1 = Cells(x, 2).Characters(Start:=y, Length:=1).Text & txt1
                End If
            Next y
                If InStr(LCase(txt1), "entered by") = 1 Then
                Cells(Row, 4) = txt1
                Else
                Debug.Print txtl
                    For Z = 1 To 10
                    If Range("c" & Row + Z - 1).Value = "" Then

                          Cells(Row + Z - 1, 3) = txt1
                          GoTo ovdje:
                    End If
                    Next Z
                End If
ovdje:
        End If
    End If
Next x

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("b" & i).Font.Italic = True Then
            Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is is order Mr. Research Executive!!